# Extracting data from Web Table

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a web table which is spread across 3 pages and you traverse to the next page using a link.

I am trying to capture all the data present in the table but since the site loads only the first page, I am able to capture the data only from the first page and the remaining two pages are getting captured as blank.

Please advise how to change this script so that it captures the data from page 2 and 3 dynamically.

### My Code

```
    driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/table-pagination-demo.html");

    //Identify the table

    WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='table-responsive']/table/tbody"));

    //Get the number of rows from the table

    List<WebElement> table_rows = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    int row_count = table_rows.size();

    System.out.println("Number of rows present are "+row_count);

    //get the number of columns from the table

    List<WebElement> table_cols = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='myTable']/tr[1]/td"));

    int col_count = table_cols.size();

    System.out.println("Number of cols present are "+col_count);

    //Print the table data

    String firstpart = "//*[@id='myTable']/tr[";
    String secondpart = "]/td[";
    String thirdpart = "]";

    for(int row=1;row<=row_count;row++)
    {
        for(int col=1;col<=col_count;col++)
        {
            String finalXpath = firstpart+row+secondpart+col+thirdpart;
            WebElement table_data = driver.findElement(By.xpath(finalXpath));
            String table_values = table_data.getText();
            System.out.print(table_values+" | ");
        }System.out.println();
    }
```

### Result

Number of rows present are 13

Number of cols present are 7

1 | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell |

2 | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell |

3 | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell |

4 | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell |

5 | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell | Table cell |

|  |  |  |  |  |  |

|  |  |  |  |  |  |

|  |  |  |  |  |  |

|  |  |  |  |  |  |

|  |  |  |  |  |  |

|  |  |  |  |  |  |

|  |  |  |  |  |  |

|  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the 6th row and so on have the `display: none;` property, you need click next button to grab the text, add validation to make sure the row contains the property or not:

```
for(int row=1;row<=row_count;row++){
    //here, the validation
    String row_style = table_rows.get(row-1).getAttribute("style");
    if(row_style.contains("none")) {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".next_link")).click();
    }

    for(int col=1;col<=col_count;col++){
        String finalXpath = firstpart+row+secondpart+col+thirdpart;
        WebElement table_data = driver.findElement(By.xpath(finalXpath));
        String table_values = table_data.getText();
        System.out.print(table_values+" | ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It worked!!! 
Can you help me understand why have you given (row-1) above?

Comment: @Bimlesh You start the `loop` from `1`, so I just want to start the `table_rows.get(index)` from the `0`. The standard start of index is `0`.